# What are the A0xxxxxx.DLL files?

Tags: windows, defragment, dll

If you've ever watched a windows computer defrag a drive, you might have noticed that many of the files that are fragmented and need fixed have names like `A0833773.DLL`.  If you know regular expressions, I could express the filename this way:

> A\d{7}[.]DLL

Does anyone here know what those files are or what they're used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are files Windows uses to perform System Restore functions.